# "Can't find namer" error using Ngclass directive

Tags: angular

First time using Angular and following a tutorial I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong when trying to change class depending on object.

Here's the components html

```html
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox">
        {{todo.title}}
        <button class="del"></button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's the component's ts.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() todo: Todo; 

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

};

// Set Dynamic Classes

setClasses() {
  let classes = {
    todo: true, 
    'is-complete': this.todo.completed
  }     

  return classes
};
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts 27:4
Module parse failed: 'return' outside of function (27:4)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         'is-complete': this.todo.completed
|     };
>     return classes;
| }
| ;
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

    ERROR in src/app/components/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts(21,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'setClasses'.
```

Comment: `setClasses` should be inside the component class. Also don't forget to check if `todo` is null or undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setClasses` function is outside of your class. It should be within,

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() todo: Todo; 


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setClasses() {
    let classes = {
      todo: true, 
      'is-complete': this.todo.completed
    }     

    return classes
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your setClasses method into your component like so:

```
First time using Angular and following a tutorial I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong when trying to change class depending on object.

Here's the components html

<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox">
        {{todo.title}}
        <button class="del"></button>
    </p>
</div>

Here's the component's ts.

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() todo: Todo; 


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  // Set Dynamic Classes

  setClasses() {
    let classes = {
      todo: true, 
      'is-complete': this.todo.completed
    }     
    return classes
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is correct in your code except you have put setClasses function outside of component class put it inside

working demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qnp6w